# php post not working using header and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i am sending a post request using jquery `$.post` to another domain. every thing works fine but i am not getting the posted data in the requested page please check my code

jquery code

```
    var data = {mydata: 'testing'};
      $.post("http://anyurl/file.php",data,function(info){
        alert(info);
    });
```

and here is php code

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); // this is to allow another domain

$data = $_POST[“mydata”]; // assigning data to variable
echo $data; // sending back to jquery

?>
```

it does not return the data please check anyone.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know if its just for me but your variable: `$_POST[“mydata”]` should have proper quotations like `$_POST[''mydata]`

Comment: Yep, incorrect quotation marks

Comment: Curly/smart quotes; *beautiful* ***yet*** *deadly.*

Comment: @Fred-ii- like many `ex`es :)

Comment: @dbh what are you suggesting man $_POST[''mydata] this is incorrect

Comment: That bad eh,... or should I say that "good"? lol @Hanky웃Panky

Comment: @Veerendra sorry man f*cked it up had to rush out quick, its `$_POST['mydata']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get the POST variable with `single quotes` and **better** to put `exit` **after echoing** it like

```
$data = $_POST['mydata'];
echo $data; 
exit;
```

And make sure that it is posting to the given URL or not through `console`.

Comment: `Try to get the POST variable and put exit after echoing it like`

Answer (score 3):

Use `proper quotes` and use `isset()` to check the `data` set or not like,

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); // this is to allow another domain    
    print_r($_POST);// to check the post data
    $data = isset($_POST['mydata']) ? $_POST['mydata'] : "No Data";
    echo $data; // sending back to jquery
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK,It walk well when I test it.In order to reappear the error you've got,I'm trying to set the file.php into a BOM-UTF8 file and it got error in the end.`So,please check your file.php if it got a BOM before header().`

Another suggess,you can use firebug to test your ajax post process.The link in the console will show you the ajax process,such as what you've post and what is feedback.Just use console.log() instead of alert().

Comment: I like it giving the reason to down vote in the comment at least he could get some knowledge and will not suggest the same thing to someone else

It would be much appreciated if all members provide reasons for the down-vote